# Send mail to multiple recipients from data base using zf2

Tags: email, controller, zend-framework2

This is my first application using Zend Framework 2. I want to send an email to recipients retreived from a database, but each time my code displays an error. This is my code:

```
$user = new Container('user');
$db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db1');

if (!$user->offsetExists('id')) {
    $idconnected = '0';           
} else {
    $idconnected = $user->offsetGet('id');
    $mail = $db->query("SELECT email FROM user WHERE id =" . $idconnected)->execute()->current();

    $message = new Message();
    $message->addTo($mail, 'eee@web.com')
            ->addFrom('xxxx@gmail.com')
            ->setSubject('Invitation à l’événement : Soirée Latino');
    $message->addCc('xxxx@hotmail.com')
            ->addBcc("xxxx@hotmail.com");

    // Setup SMTP transport using LOGIN authentication
    $transport = new SmtpTransport();
    $options = new SmtpOptions(array(
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'connection_class' => 'login',
        'connection_config' => array(
            'ssl' => 'tls',
            'username' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
            'password' => '*********'
        ),
        'port' => 587,
    ));
    $html = new MimePart('<b>Invitation for the event: Latin Night, orgonized by Mr. Jony Cornillon <i>Date : 06/04/2015</i></b>');
    $html->type = "text/html";
    $body = new MimeMessage();
    $body->addPart($html);
    //$body->setParts(array($html));

    $message->setBody($body);

    $transport->setOptions($options);
    $transport->send($message);
}
```

And this is the error:

```
5.1.2 We weren't able to find the recipient domain. Please check for any
5.1.2 spelling errors, and make sure you didn't enter any spaces,      periods,
5.1.2 or other punctuation after the recipient's email address.   a13sm19808164wjx.30 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this code, and now it works fine :

```
    foreach ($mail as $recip) {
    $message->addTo($recip);
    $message->addTo('samehmay@hotmail.com', 'eee@web.com')
                ->addFrom('maysameh0@gmail.com')
                ->setSubject('Invitation à l’événement : Soirée Latino');
    }
```